# How can i assign an id to an Polygon after it completed with drawingManager on google-map

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the drawingManager to let user draw Polygon on the map which works fine. Part of the functionality is to save the polygons, so a user can have 1 or more items to save. To keep track I save them to an array
of Polygons. Here is where i am running into issues..

When a user initial creates a polygon, how can i set a custom key like ID on that polygon so i can save it in my array with the polygon path ? That way on any change I know which Polygon I have to update or possibly delete ?

When i load the polygon from code i can do it like this..

```
  const polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      draggable: true,
      editable: true,
      paths: this.polygonPts,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      id: 'a1b484c5-0584-49c7-8263-442b9dfbe57b',
    });
```

even so it works the system complains with :

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not
> exist in type 'PolygonOptions'.

So my question is how could i assign a value to a custom key in PolygonOptions and also is the only way to get rid of this error to extend the 'PolygonOptions' Interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you work with [Google Maps' data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), you cannot specify extra properties to your overlays. The data layer allows you to work with custom properties.

That being said, why not use create your own mapping object? Something like this:

```js
const polygonsById = {
    'a1b484c5-0584-49c7-8263-442b9dfbe57b': polygon1,
    'a1b484c5-0584-49c7-8263-123456789012': polygon2,
    ...
};
```

#### Edit

I see your question is tagged with `angular`. Try the `@bespunky/angular-google-maps` library. It's very flexible. In the sense of overlays, you can set a `custom` field with any data you want on each overlay (polygon in your case).

[Docs for attaching custom values](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/docs/additional-documentation/programmatic-control.html#custom-data)

[Live example for custom values](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/Programmatic%20Control/Custom%20Data)

[Getting started with @bespunky/angular-google-maps](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/docs/additional-documentation/getting-started/plug-n-play-async-loading.html)

> The library tracks your overlays for you. You won't have to create any mapping yourself and you'll get other benefits.

> npm install @bespunky/angular-google-maps

Comment: I take bespunky is another one like agm maps. I used that before but didn’t like the duplicated way on how you have to implement stuff. Some will be via code then other parts use a *ngIf template. I had that with agm and went to pure google map because registering event listeners for polygon edits didn’t work for me.

Comment: `@bespunky/angular-google-maps` is more flexible then agm. **You** decide how to use it... Only in your code, only in your template, or mix the two. Have a look at the [overlays superpower](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/docs/additional-documentation/overlays-superpower.html#the-superpower) and the [programmatic control](https://bs-angular-g-maps.web.app/docs/additional-documentation/programmatic-control.html) topics.

Comment: Thanks, after a bit more digging i was able to find a way to set the id when the polycom was drawn and then use it to add and maintain an array of its path. It is just cleaner then mixing multiple implementations. That's why i left  agm maps.